# Easier way to print rows of boxes to console?

Tags: c#, console-application

I was wondering, I am making a calculator C# console application just to practice the language, and I have set up a little display that prints boxes of zeros that contain a number. I have set up a sort of legend below it, so each number corresponds with an equation, e.g. 1 = Area of a shape, 2 = Functions. It prints correctly, but the problem is that my code looks as follows:

```
static void WriteMenu()
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n \n");
    Console.WriteLine("  OOOOOOOO     OOOOOOOO     OOOOOOOO     OOOOOOOO     OOOOOOOO\n  O      O     O      O     O      O     O      O     O      O");
    Console.WriteLine("  O  1   O     O  2   O     O  3   O     O  4   O     O  5   O\n  O      O     O      O     O      O     O      O     O      O");
    Console.WriteLine("  OOOOOOOO     OOOOOOOO     OOOOOOOO     OOOOOOOO     OOOOOOOO");
    Console.WriteLine("\n \n");
    Console.WriteLine("  OOOOOOOO     OOOOOOOO     OOOOOOOO     OOOOOOOO     OOOOOOOO\n  O      O     O      O     O      O     O      O     O      O");
    Console.WriteLine("  O  6   O     O  7   O     O  8   O     O  9   O     O  10  O\n  O      O     O      O     O      O     O      O     O      O");
    Console.WriteLine("  OOOOOOOO     OOOOOOOO     OOOOOOOO     OOOOOOOO     OOOOOOOO");            
}
```

I just wanted to know if there was an easier way, so if in the future if I wanted to do anything of the sort (printing groups of text) without an ugly bunch of WriteLines. I am, as mentioned before, a beginner, so I don't know a ton about the language.

The way it should print is 2x4, which is where the main difficulty comes from.

Comment: Did you know ascii has box drawing characters?  Sample: `├────────┤`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can divide single box into separate lines. Create a variable for each line. And then depending on how many boxes you need you add the line as many times as you need. Encapsulate that into a separate method and invoke it as many times as you need. The example below builds boxes for simple integers:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> numbers1 = new List<int>() { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        List<int> numbers2 = new List<int>() { 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

        DisplayBoxedInts(numbers1);
        DisplayBoxedInts(numbers2);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void DisplayBoxedInts(IEnumerable<int> numbers)
    {
        var boxLine1 = "ooooooo ";
        var boxLine2 = "o     o ";
        var boxLine3 = "o  {0}  o ";
        var boxLine4 = "o     o ";
        var boxLine5 = "ooooooo ";

        var count = numbers.Count();

        var multiBoxLine1 = string.Empty;
        var multiBoxLine2 = string.Empty;
        var multiBoxLine3 = string.Empty;
        var multiBoxLine4 = string.Empty;
        var multiBoxLine5 = string.Empty;

        foreach (var num in numbers)
        {
            multiBoxLine1 += boxLine1;
            multiBoxLine2 += boxLine2;
            multiBoxLine3 += string.Format(boxLine3, num);
            multiBoxLine4 += boxLine4;
            multiBoxLine5 += boxLine5;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(multiBoxLine1);
        Console.WriteLine(multiBoxLine2);
        Console.WriteLine(multiBoxLine3);
        Console.WriteLine(multiBoxLine4);
        Console.WriteLine(multiBoxLine5);
    }
}
```

The result is similar to yours:

[image]

Note however that this solution works with single integers. If they start growing bigger you have to think of better aligning sides of the boxes. Perhaps adding `\t` between content of the box and its side.

Comment: Indeed this did work! I don't know if you meant to or not though, but you need to add using System.Collections.Generic and System.Linq for the code to run properly. You also fixed my problem of why my compiler didnt let me use lists! bravo.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `@` (verbatim string literal modifier) on a string:

```
var text = @"This
is my multi-
line string";
```